# How to Find Children Element in @ViewChild Angular2?

Tags: angular

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div #container>
        <p>para 1</p>
        <p>para 2</p>
        <button>button 1</button>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('container') myDiv;

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    //this console.log would print this [p, p, button]
    console.log(this.myDiv.nativeElement.children);
    //how can I access to only p nativeElement only? 
  } 

}
```

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cfV4lU1uccpsSox0jYTh?p=preview)

Comment: `Array.from(this.myDiv.nativeElement.children).filter(tag => tag.tagName === 'P')` returns only p elements

Comment: Great, that's the solution. It also works with Renderer. Please answer the question, so I can mark it as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the following to get array of `p` elements:

```
Array.from(this.myDiv.nativeElement.children).filter(tag => tag.tagName === 'P')
```