# Angular2 get Div position of given #id

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am Building a TimeLine Schedule in Angular2, by doing following:

```
        <div class="timelineRow" *ngFor="let team of teams">
            <div class="RowDescriptionColumn">{{team.title}}</div>
            <div class="scheduleblock" *ngFor="let date of dates; let index=index; let odd=odd; let even=even;">
                <div class="timeslot1" [ngClass]="{ odd: odd, even: even }" [attr.id]="team.teamId +'_'+ date.id +'_ts1'"></div>
                <div class="timeslot2" [ngClass]="{ odd: odd, even: even }" [attr.id]="team.teamId +'_'+ date.id +'_ts2'"></div>
                <div class="timeslot3" [ngClass]="{ odd: odd, even: even }" [attr.id]="team.teamId +'_'+ date.id +'_ts3'"></div>
                <div class="timeslot4" [ngClass]="{ odd: odd, even: even }" [attr.id]="team.teamId +'_'+ date.id +'_ts4'"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="eventBlock" *ngFor="let event of events" [style.left]="getPosition(team, event)">{{event.title}}</div>
        </div>
```

So first i build the timeslots (4 per date) and afterwards, on top of these Timslot-Divs i want to lay the Events. The Event has to start on the correct Date, so i try to get the Position by doing a jQuery (i know: evil)..

```
getPosition(team, event): string {
    if (this.dates) {
      let left = "0px";
      let found = this.dates.filter(myObj => new Date(myObj.date).toDateString() === new Date(event.start).toDateString())[0];
      if (found) {
        let pos = jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('#' + team.teamId + '_' + found.id + '_' + 'ts3').position();
        console.log(pos);
        if (pos) {
          left = pos.left + "px";
        }
      }
      return left;
    }
  }
```

this doesnt work, but i cant figure out how to get the starting Position of the "underlaying" Timeslot-Div..

P.

Comment: Is console is giving you correct value? I suspect getPostion is called too early.  Can you let it create them first and reposition in ngAfterViewInit via ViewChildren. Viewchildren usage : http://stackoverflow.com/q/38149322/652850

Comment: created an identifier on the timslotRow bij adding the '#timeLineRow' and implementing the ngAfterViewInit, the  myDiv in this ngAfterViewInit (@ViewChild('timeLineRow') myDiv;) is empty... 
When breaking in the Console, ngAfterViewInit is called before the Rendering is finished :(

Comment: entered too soon :)

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: ngAfterViewChecked() {} is the correct Answer :)

ngAfterViewInit, the *ngFor isnt ready yet, ngAfterViewChecked, then the DOM is ready.

Now i get a list of timeslotRows. so now i can find the stuff i Need (i think :))

Comment: Make sense but this is going to be called multiple times so add proper checks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect getPostion is called too early. Can you let view create the components and then reposition in `ngAfterViewChecked` using ViewChildren/ ViewChild . 
See [Viewchildren usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38149322/652850)
`ngAfterViewChecked` is called multiple times so make sure your reposition logic is not called again