# Having trouble getting html elements of a component after page load ng2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a web app that uses ng2-smart-table.  I am trying to retrieve all the cells and apply a hidden attribute to them.  I thought that putting

```
cells = document.getElementsbyTagName("td")
```

in ngAfterViewInit() would do the trick but I don't think the table has finished loading at that point because I get an htmlCollection of size 0.  So I thought I would try to use callback functions. So I used this code in ngAfterViewInit() (first time using callback functions so I'm not sure if this is correct).

```
  let getCells = function(){
    return document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  }
  let changeCells = function(callback){
    let data = callback();
    console.log(data.length);
    if(data.length !== 1189){ changeCells(callback) }
    else{ console.log(data.length); }
  }

  changeCells(getCells);
```

1189 is how many cells there are.  I know this because I put the following code in ngAfterViewInit() and it gave me back that value (the value I expected).

```
  document.getElementById("columnButtonModal").setAttribute("href", "#columnInfoModal");
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("td").length);
  }, 150);
```

So in my callback function it just executes indefinitley until I run out of stack space.  I know I can use the setTimeout function but I feel like that is not an appropriate solution to this problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is my ngOnInit() and ngAfterViewInit() code.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.routingSubscription = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.var = params["val"] || 'all';
    this.source = new ServerDataSource(this.http, { endPoint: `webaddress` });
  });
```

}

```
ngAfterViewInit(){

    let getCells = function(){
      return document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    }
    let changeCells = function(callback){
      let data = callback();
      console.log(data.length);
      if(data.length !== 1189){ changeCells(callback) }
      else{ console.log(data.length); }
    }

    changeCells(getCells);
/*
    document.getElementById("columnButtonModal").setAttribute("href", "#columnInfoModal");
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("td").length);
    }, 150);
*/
  }
```

Comment: Getting handle on elements via `document.` is a bad practice in Angular. Why don't you use `@ViewChildren` instead? [ViewChildren documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38149322/how-to-find-children-element-in-viewchild-angular2) should suffice for solving your problem

Comment: Hm, I got tunnel vision on this one method.  I will look into viewChildren.  I would still like to know why the above is not working.

Comment: Ah, it's uppercase in my code. Yeah, an error message would be nice but I do not get one from typescript or browser console.

Answer (score 1):

The *direct* root of your problem is the recursive call.

```
let changeCells = function (callback) {
  ...
  if (data.length !== 1189) { // <- The `data.length` does not become equal to 1189
    changeCells(callback);    // ...but the function is being recursively invoked,
                              // while `data` has not changed...
  }
}
```

You need to either not have this nested recursive call altogether; or make sure the data is adjusted to eventually contain exactly `1189` elements, otherwise your code will keep running out of stack...

Comment: The data.length should be 1189 after the page loads.  If I shouldn't do the recursive call then how can I edit the callback function so that any commands don't execute until the page is loaded and the data variable contains all the cells?

Comment: @user3736114 you should understand that `The data.length should be 1189 after the page loads.` may never happen at all. Recursion is not an answer here. Also, in angular you do not use callbacks really for responding to data fetching. Please, show how you are calling the API to retrieve the data.

Comment: You are right.  This was not the right approach.  Using the @ViewChild made this much more simple.  I now have access to the component elements.  Now sure how to add an *ngIf statement to it but I am closer.  thank you for your help.

Comment: @user3736114 consider up voting/accepting the answer if it was helpful to you